# Plot graph with x-axis showing weeks and year

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
dat <- data.frame(
  weeks = c(23,24,25,26,23)
  year = c(2022,2022,2022,2023,2023),
  cases = c(70,98,69,430,56)
  
)
```

Now I am trying to plot this data using ggplot2

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=factor(weeks), y=cases)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I did like to have the x-axis split showing **weeks in 2022** and **weeks in 2023**.

something like this
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: How is week 67 in one year possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, using `facet_grid` then place the group outside using `stri.placement`

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=factor(weeks), y=cases)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_grid(. ~ year, scales = "free", switch = "x", space = "free_x") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```